# I love pictures on my phone - what does zero article imply?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles

Please, look at the sentence:

*"I love pictures on my phone"*

What can it mean?

1) I love all the pictures that are now on my phone with no exceptions?

2) I love most of the pictures that are now on my phone?

3) I love having pictures on my phone?

4) I love some previously unmentioned pictures on my phone?

Thanks.

Comment: To me the third option is the one that best reflects what the sentence suggests.

Answer (score 7):

The most natural interpretation is *I love the ability to have pictures on my phone*, which is essentially your #3.  A native speaker would not interpret it as #1, #2 or #4.  If you inserted the definite article ("the") before *pictures* it would no longer mean #3, and #1, #2 and #4 would all be plausible.

Comment: also, i don't think many native speakers would use the sentence in the question, period. if they mean *I love the ability to have pictures on my phone*, they would say *I love having pictures on my phone.*

Answer (score 0):

I think it means "I love the ability to **take pictures** on my phone."

It's likely not possessing the pictures that they find exciting, but the ability to take them.

Answer (score -1):

Break it down grammatically.

*I* is the subject. *I* is the person or thing doing the verb.

*Love* is the verb. It's what the subject is doing.

*Pictures* is the object of the verb. It's the person or thing that is loved.

*On* is a preposition. It begins a prepositional phrase that will modify *pictures*.

*My phone* is the object of the preposition *on*. It describes how or in what way the pictures are *on*.

Another way you could phrase this sentence is, "There are pictures on my phone, and I love them." The sentence does not definitely establish how many of them you love (be it all, most, or only some)--only that the subject loves pictures on his or her phone.

If this question were in ELL, I'd sooner assume that the sentence might be formatted incorrectly to carry its meaning, since the verbiage used isn't commonly used to say what the sentence actually says. If this is a matter of interpreting someone else's words in a non-literal way, your third suggestion is probably the most likely guess.

Comment: None of the options fit the sentence, if the sentence is to be interpreted literally.

Comment: This breakdown doesn't actually help disambiguate. You break it down, but then say "three is probably the most likely" without any relevance to the breakdown, and in fact, contradicting the "another way you could phrase" you've given.

Comment: Because if 3 is the correct answer (as it might appear on a less than perfectly written ELL test, for example), there is no good justification for why it is the correct answer. Interpreted literally, the answer is not found among the provided options.

Comment: Of course there is good justification. There is an elliptical construction ("I love (the possibility of) having pictures on my phone") that's hiding in the sentence structure, not in the words themselves - so a word-by-word breakdown isn't a good way of showing it.

Comment: You can't just make up words and stick them in a sentence, except in cases of specific types of inference such as an inferred subject. Least of all, you shouldn't do without more context from the rest of the conversation. Adding words changes the meaning of the sentence as it is written, and that's outside the bounds of justifiable interpretation. Either the correct interpretation of the sentence is not included in the four options given or the sentence is poorly written (such that it does not effectively communicate what is meant).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can I say it like this and will it be correct? "I like pictures on my sd-card. The pictures are nice" ? Like my meaning #4 - if this is the first mention of the pictures and the listener didn't know I had any there? Thanks.