# I love pictures on my phone. The pictures are nice

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-articles

There is a set of sentences:

"I love pictures on my phone. The pictures are nice."

In a thread

[I love pictures on my phone - what does zero article imply?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207387/i-love-pictures-on-my-phone-what-does-zero-article-imply/207452#207452)

I was told that the meaning of the first sentence is more likely that I like having photos on my phone.

Buy can I use this set of sentences, when I mention those pictures for the first time in the first sentence, talking about real pictures, with no article, assuming the listener doesn't know that I have any pictures on my phone, and then say "the pictures"? Is it appropriate then?

Thanks.

Comment: Your two sentences are not incompatible. "I like having photos on my phone. The photos I have on my phone are nice." One is general; the other narrows down to a particular set of pictures -- those on your phone. You can omit *on my phone* in the second sentence because that's understood.

Answer (score 1):

It seems highly awkward and clumsy to me; I would say no, you cannot.

The definite article has many uses. You seem to be wanting to leave it out here because of the half-truth often stated that a definite article requires that the noun phrase in question be already within the scope of the discourse. This is not entirely false, but it only a part of the whole truth.

Another function of the definite article is to signal that the noun phrase is somehow modified or more narrowly defined than the bare noun (phrase) itself.

Thus, for example, it is perfectly natural that the second paragraph in this answer starts with “the definite article” since the definite article has already been introduced in your question and is within the scope of our current (virtual) discourse. In the next line, it is also natural that I use “the noun phrase” because it is modified and narrowed down by “in question”. If this narrowing down had not been present, the sentence would have been awkward:

> … a definite article requires that the noun phrase be already within the scope of the discourse

– would not work *in this context* since “noun phrase” is not something that exists in the scope of the discourse.

In your example, “on my phone” narrows down the head of the noun phrase, “pictures”, which means that it is perfectly natural to use a definite article. You are in fact referring to a specific, *definite* subset of pictures, namely the ones that are located on your phone.

Leaving out the definite article is fine in the sentence itself—as stated in the thread you link to, it simply forces “pictures” to refer to an *indefinite*, undefine set of pictures, which is then taken to be just *any* possible pictures and ends up meaning that you love *having* pictures on your phone. An undefined, vague notion of “pictures” is introduced into the scope of the discourse, but it remains to some degree ‘unreferenced’, as it were.

There is nothing wrong with this, but since the next sentence uses “the pictures” without narrowing down the set of pictures, *this* instance of the definite article does require that a specific, defined set of “pictures” be available in the discourse—and no such set is found. Only a looser, undefined set of “pictures” is found, which is not enough.

Comment: Well, I see, thanks for the great explanation! I asked one native speaker and he told me that when I say "I used cars of my friend", I should omit "the" before cars, if the listener doesn't know that my friend has cars. Is it just another case? Not just like with "I like + bare infinitive"?

Comment: No, your friend is just simply wrong. “I used cars of my friend” is completely ungrammatical. I cannot imagine any native speaker of English saying that. First of all, a [Saxon genitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive) would be expected (which does not permit a definite article on the thing possessed): “I used _my friend’s car_”. But even if an _of_ genitive were used, a definite article would be mandatory: “I used the car(s) of my friend”.

Comment: Thanks? But can I say "I used a car my friend has" or "I used a car of my friend"? Can it be used for the first mention? Can it be used, if a friend has several cars so it is unclear for the listener which one I used? Thanks.

Comment: You can say, “I used a car my friend has/owns”. You can also say, “I used one of my friend’s cars” or (less idiomatically) “I used a car of my friend’s”, but ‘a car of my friend’ does not work. We generally do not use the _of_ possessive with concrete people when the possession is one of literal ownership.

Comment: Thanks. But if the was one car, I could say "The car of my friend" for the first mention? You say that of-genetive is not used in this manner with literal ownership, but I got the sentence I wrote here from your answer which is before yours last one... So why here we use it that way? Is it because "car" is singular" there?

Comment: You _could_ say “the car of my friend”, but people would almost certainly consider it unnatural and foreign. The normal, natural way of saying it is “my friend’s car”, as I said in my first comment as well, using a Saxon genitive. People would understand “a/the car of my friend” just fine, but it is not idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just have one little question. When we say an object to a speaker who we know is unfamiliar with the term, does it influence our choose of definite article? I mean, if I say: "I saw the ahssajsad of my friend's" - is it correct using "the", even if this is the first mention and the person has no idea what "ahssajsad" means? Does definite article always has to do with specifity not familiarity? Thanks.

Comment: When you use the ‘double possessive’ (a car of my friend’s), the meaning is “one car out of all my friend’s [cars]”, so you cannot use the definite article at all there—it is inherently indefinite. And with people, the construction still sounds awkward. It’s much better to say “one of my friend’s cars”.

Comment: Thanks. If I say - I used the car of my colleague - It means he has only one?

Comment: Not necessarily—but it doesn’t mean that he definitely has _more_ than one, either. If you go through life holding the hand of the person you love, that doesn’t imply that person only has one hand.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I still don't understand one thing. and might have expressed myself incorrectly. When we say some concept the listener doesn't know about, be it a new word or discovery, or scientific term, does it play any role in selecting an article. If one says to a friend who knows no terms of computer networking: "It was made with the hub taken from their office" - and the person has never heard the word "hub" before this very moment, will it still be correct?

Comment: Yes, perfectly correct. Whether the other person has ever heard of the thing in question doesn’t change anything—it cannot possibly, because you, as the speaker, cannot possibly know what others have and have not heard of. “It was made with a hub taken from their office” would be used if the hub is new to the discourse; “It was made with the hub taken from their office” would be used if the hub is already in scope.